# How can I get the full Windows 10 Notification messages (they are truncated)

Tags: windows-10, notifications, notification-area, windows-defender

Notifications in Windows 10 truncate reasonably important data. For instance, Defender is telling me a program is changing my folder, but it wont give the full message (path to exe):

[image]

Now, this I can figure this program out, but is there a way to get access to the full notifications somewhere?

Comment: [Windows Defender AV event IDs and error codes | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/troubleshoot-windows-defender-antivirus)?

Comment: Verify your path variable isn't to long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looked for the same thing and found this solution here:
https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/39902-any-way-review-notifications-history.html

> Often you can find the notifications in the Event Viewer. We are all used to looking in the Applications and System logs, but almost all apps and services also have their own log area in Event Viewer. For example I wanted to look at past Windows Defender notifications, mostly because they get truncated in the notification center and that makes it really useless for figuring out what triggered the notification if the path is long, etc.
>
> 1. Open Event Viewer
> 2. Expand Applications and Services Logs
> 3. Drill down to the app or service you are interested in, e.g. for Windows Defender you might go to: **Microsoft** -> **Windows** -> **Windows Defender** -> **Operational** log.
> 4. Review the log and look for the notification you were interested in.

That will give you the full notifications you need. Note that it may be listed as a warning, information, etc.

Comment: while this may be acceptable to review a single or a few notifications, this gets annoying really fast if you get them fairly frequently. is there a way to display the full text right when it pops up? Also the program that gives me those messages (Visual Studio) is not listed there in the event viewer. The notification windows defender is putting a duplicate there, but other notification messages may not. So your solution works for Windows Defender only.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't find any notifications in there :/

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find these notifications in the Event Viewer, you can use paid [Notification Logger](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/notification-logger/9mzf9dmhnh3p) app from Microsoft Store to view past notifications history.

Comment: Do you get these notifications from Event viewer, or is there more comprehensive log in windows, if so where? Thanks.

Comment: They are not from any windows log, they are caught on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The linked discussion https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/39902-any-way-review-notifications-history.html now has a better solution that worked for me. The earlier answer didn't help me as I was interested in a notification from a program that doesn't create logs that Event Viewer shows.

The notifications are stored in an SQLite database at `\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\wpndatabase.db`. I used *DB Browser for SQLite* to view it. The database has a number of tables in it; the "Notification" table contains the notifications, and its "Payload" column contains the full text of each notification.

Answer (score 1):

The method I now employ is using [Textify](https://ramensoftware.com/textify) on notifications; much quicker than inspecting the SQLite database.

I have been using Textify for copying uncopiable text from various Windows dialogs. I found that, using it on a Windows notification via its mouse or keyboard shortcut displays the whole text of the notification, and automatically copies it (auto copy can be disabled in settings).

Comment: Nice little tool. 2 little caveats on Windows 11: 1. you need to click on the notification image or empty area for Textify to recognize the text (clicking the text itself does not trigger Textify). --- 2. The Textify window containing the copiable text, unfortunately, pops up *behind* the notification bar.